# Copy content from webpage and paste it in another website to search in Edge or Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Need help please.
How can I achieve the following?

I use https://spur.us/context website to investigate IP addresses.
Currently I am having to copy IP address from a website and paste manually in the spur.us website which is time consuming. I want to make this process quicker.

How can I just select an IP address like shows in below image and open in separate website by attaching the copied content like https://spur.us/context/20.238.65.64

[image]

Is there any tool/extensions I can use or setting within browser?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

quick way is, you can customize browser search engine check this [https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513882?hl=en#:~:text=From%20the%20Programmable%20Search%20Engine,can%20always%20add%20more%20later](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513882?hl=en#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Programmable%20Search%20Engine,can%20always%20add%20more%20later).
I don't think if there is an extension exists for this purpose.
Any experienced Extension developer, including me, can make one you. feel free to connect.

Comment: It does the job but its not what I am looking for. Thank you for taking time and answering. Appreciated.

Comment: you need a custom context menu  that is possible through an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you need to navigate to https://spur.us/context/20.238.65.64 by only selecting `20.238.65.64` and performing some sort of action within a single page? It looks like the context menu wouldn't help (**the browser would directly lead you to this ip address instead of searching for it**), but you can achieve it by specifying your own search engine. Please go to the following url for search engine setting.

Edge: `edge://settings/searchEngines?search=engine`

Chrome: `chrome://settings/searchEngines?search=search+engine`

You can add `spur.us` as a search engine. You need to choose **Make default** after adding it and make sure your search engine url looks like this: https://spur.us/context/%s

Then, you need to

1. Copy the ip address.
2. Press `Ctrl+E` to call the default search engine.
3. Paste the ip address.

Now you will be able to see the expected result. Though it may not be exactly what you've asked for, I think it does smooth the work flow. Remember to make default your previous default search engine after the work is finished.

Comment: It helps but not fully. Thank you for taking time and answering. Appreciated.